# Is this Pomegranate Molasses rescuable?

Tags: reduction, mistakes

I was trying to make [Alton Brown's Pomegranate Molasses](https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/pomegranate-syrup-or-molasses-recipe-1947699), but had trouble converting his "medium-low heat" to my electric (glass top) stove.

I ended up with what commenters on the above link describe as "Pomegranate Candy" because I let it get too thick and it solidified as it cooled.

Other than starting again with lower heat or less time, is there any way to rescue it? Can I reheat it with more pomegranate juice (or plain water) added to rehydrate it somehow?

Comment: FWIW, you can buy pomegranate molasses in many stores, and online, now, if you wanna save yourself a lot of effort.

Comment: @FuzzyChef I have checked every grocery store in our area, including the "gourmet" stores, and no one has it. It doesn't matter now, because it didn't take very long to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can dissolve your pomegranate candy in plain water and cook it to a more usable consistency. A candy thermometer is useful here. But if you have any instant read thermometer for cooking, you should aim for around 220°F (104°C) max. If you get to 230°F (110°C), you'll be making candy again.

If you don't have a thermometer handy, I recommend getting a cup of ice. As you recook your syrup and notice it start to reduce, take a spoonful and drip a little onto your ice. That will chill it quickly and allow you to see where the final product will be texturally.